# How to configure SSO using OAuth and OpenID connect for AD2BC

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How to configure SSO using OAuth and OpenID connect for AD2BC for Azure ADB2C?

Comment: Have you looked at it? Are there problems? SO is not really a "provide me a step-by-step -list" site. That's something you can ask when you pay people.

Answer (score 0):

When you protect multiple apps with AAD B2C, SSO is enabled by default. There is no configuration needed. You can adjust the configuration of the SSO as seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior